# Is that possible to install socket.io client in main script?

Tags: socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm using Laravel-echo. For now i only able to include socket.io script before the main app.js. That's making page entirely slow. So... is that possible to use them in the same file?

The problem is that we must use a js file that server generate automatically.

[image]

Comment: You can put the `<script`> tag for `socket.io.js` wherever you want in the main page as long as you don't attempt to use `socket.io` in any code that is loaded before the `socket.io.js` file is loaded.  However, there is ZERO reason why the `socket.io.js` file should be slow to load so if you are actually seeing that, then you should just work to fix that, not work around it.  Some profiling on your server is probably what you need to do next to see why it's slow to respond.  Or, if you're loading it from a CDN, then perhaps there is a problem with that CDN.

Comment: Since laravel is PHP-based, I'm wondering if there's some sort of server-startup code you're seeing in the first request to your Laravel PHP server that will fall to whatever is the first request, even if you reorder things.  I'd suggest some sleuthing on the server side to see why things are so slow.  One thing to test is to see if the second web page you open while keeping the first page open (on the same browser) is just as slow as the first.  Then, try with two different browsers that both have open pages.   Then try from two different computers each with a page open.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well. This is not so dramatically slow. That was a bad example on screenshot. Usually app.js loads after socket.io. But also i'm using vue.js for some things, and now with socket io i see a little blink when dom isn't ready. So...i cannot put vue before socket.io because in this case i have to use two different instances of vue. And also i have to use event listener in main file, so it's requiring socket.io. Maybe this is my fault, that it's could work only like that. I just wanted to know is there any other way. But thanks

Comment: Well 655ms for socket.io.js to load is dramatically slow.  That's what you show.  You need to fix the 655ms in the back-end, not just rearrange the deck chairs on your titanic.  Rearranging will still leave something slow if your server is that slow.

Comment: For reference, I have a web page that uses socket.io and the server is running on a little tiny Raspberry PI server and I get 169ms to load socket.io.js from a clear cache and only 25ms after the first time.